# formatting active tab in Easy responsive tabs in aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am using [easy-responsive-tabs](http://webtrendset.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html) in my asp.net project. I have two vertical tabs (li)

when one is active then html looks like this:

```
tab-bg-top resp-tab-item resp-tab-active
tab-bg-bottom resp-tab-item
```

when other is active then style sheet looks like this:

```
tab-bg-top resp-tab-item 
tab-bg-bottom resp-tab-item resp-tab-active
```

I want to apply following style to bottom tab when active:

```
border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left:1px #666666 dashed;border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;
```

and following style when above tab is active

```
border-bottom: none;border-right: none;border-left:1px #666666 dashed;border-top:1px #666666 dashed;
```

How can I apply these styles to following li's

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
                        <li class="tab-bg-top resp-tab-item resp-tab-active" aria-controls="tab_item-0" role="tab">Jobs</li>
                        <li style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left:1px #666666 dashed;border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;" class="tab-bg-bottom resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-1" role="tab">Personnel</li>
</ul>
```

Please note, I have applied it manually so far.

Please suggest

Comment: Simply use [Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Comment: @Murali and if that has any issue then i use some other plugin ? and so on ?